# BETWEEN PHP comparar datas

Tags: php

Estou fazendo uma agenda online e preciso verificar os horários que já estão agendados para não dar conflito com o horario para agendar.

Estou utilizando o BETWEEN do PHP para comparar os horários, porém não está dando certo.

Exemplo

Horário a ser agendado

```
inicio: 2019-03-11 09:30:00
Final: 2019-03-11 09:45:00
```

No banco tenho cadastrado:

```
inicio: 2019-03-11 09:00:00
Final: 2019-03-11 10:00:00
```

Seleciono o banco para poder fazer a verificação do horário a ser agendado:

```
$valor_start= $hoje->format('Y-m-d '.trim($_POST['hora_inicio']).":00".'') ;
$valor_end= $hoje->format('Y-m-d '.trim($_POST['hora_final']).":00".'');

$sql="SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE `start` BETWEEN '".implode('-', array_reverse(explode('/', substr($valor_start, 0, 10)))).substr($valor_start, 10)."' AND '".implode('-', array_reverse(explode('/', substr($valor_end, 0, 10)))).substr($valor_end, 10)."' and ativo='sim' and atendente='".$_POST['atendente']."'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        ?>

<div class="col-md-6 ">
<div class="borda_data_erro">
<p><b><strong>Esse dia e horário já existe em Consultas abertas</strong> </b></p>
<p><i class="m-r-10 mdi mdi-calendar-remove"></i> Início: <b><? echo $valor_start ."-".$row['start']?></b></p>
<p><i class="m-r-10 mdi mdi-calendar-remove"></i> Final: <b><? echo $valor_end ."-".$row['end']?></b></p>
</div>      
</div>      
        <?

        $checar_horarios=$row['start'];

}}
```

Deveria retornar o erro **Esse dia e horário já existe em Consultas abertas** mas não acontece isso, como poderia resolver?

Comment: Qual é o resultado desse `$result` roda um `var_dump($result)` e me fala o resultado  ?

Comment: O campo data está como varchar? pq essa conversão no formato?

Comment: porque vem do formulario assim 11/03/2019

Comment: @Bulfaitelo o var_dump($result) retorna isso object(mysqli_result)#6 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(10) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(0) }

Comment: Roda um `var_dump($sql)`

Comment: retorna isso string(124) "SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE `start` BETWEEN '2019-03-11 9:30:00' AND '2019-03-11 9:45:00' and ativo='sim' and atendente='2'"

Comment: Para te esclarecer, `BETWEEN` é um operador do SQL, não do PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está fazendo um select buscando na tabela onde o start está entre `2019-03-11 9:30:00` e `2019-03-11 9:45:00`, e pelo oque você falou, o horário de start que está cadastrado no banco é `2019-03-11 09:00:00`, ou seja, seu select não vai retornar nada pois `2019-03-11 09:00:00` não está entre os valores que foram passados pelo seu select, então ele não vai entrar dentro do `if` e consequentemente não irá retornar o erro `Esse dia e horário já existe em Consultas abertas`. Ou seja, seu código está correto, você apenas está se confundido com os valores no select.